# PATH_INFO stops working after internal redirect?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, fastcgi

I have been at this for 45 minutes with no luck. I've found similar questions, but none that fully address my situation/problem.

I am trying to do a rewrite that does 2 things: 1) makes clean URL's (removes index.php) 2) hides a directory (my app is at web_root/dir, but I want it appear at domain.com/) 3) leaves $_SERVER('PATH_INFO') unchanged

So, for example. I want:

```
www.mydomain.com/some/path
```

to internally rewrite to:

```
www.mydomain.com/dir/index.php/some/path
```

This is what I have so far:

```
RewriteBase   /dir/
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dir.*$
# if I change the [L] to an [R], it all works
# but it obviously "dirties" my desired clean URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dir/index.php/$1 [L]

# not sure why I need this
RewriteRule ^/?$ /dir/
```

I should at: there is a proxy at my institution, but I don't think its causing the problem.

Using PHP 5.3 and FastCGI

What's the secret to keep PATH_INFO working with an internal redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm! Trailing path stuff.

So this path info is being lost in the rewrites?

Have you tried doing the `www.mydomain.com/some/path` -> `www.mydomain.com/dir/index.php/some/path` rewrite not in the per-directory context, but earlier in the server's URL handling, like VirtualHost?

I'm thinking that doing it on URL's cannot lose the path info because it is not know at that time which part is physical path and which is trailing junk. Not util the URL is mapped to a file. If you produce the

Heck, how about a simple `Alias`? Aliases are often used to map abstract URL locations to concrete places in the filesystem for applications. I have a whole bunch of them; here is one:

```
Alias /cgit/txr /cgit/cgit.cgi/txr
```

When people access `www.kylheku.com/cgit/txr` it redirects internally to `www.kylheku.com/cgit/cgit.cgi/txr`.  That URL will work too, but the former one is nicer, because it doesn't have three repetitions of the string `cgi`.

Needless to say, the alias doesn't lose any trailing stuff from the URL.

Comment: This has prompted me to re-examine my `Alias` and I found something "neat". The reason I had `Alias /cgit/txr /cgit/cgit.cgi/txr` (repository specific, and done that way for several others) instead of just aliasing `/cgit/` to `/cgit/cgit.cgi` was that there is a style sheet located at `/cgit/cgit.css` which gets rewritten also and is then not found. But, it turns you you can fix that by having an earlier `Alias /cgit/cgit.css /cgit/cgit.css`! Aliases are not re-examined for more alias expansion, so anything you map to itself is left alone. Didn't know that! So, two simple rules now for cgit.

Comment: Kaz, Great idea, with the alias, but does not entirely suit my needs. I want to keep some stuff at /, but rewrite anything that does not map onto a file to /dir (I have an app there that is the "main" site, which I want to keep separate from other files I may add at the document root. Any other ideas?